# I am not exactly sure of the behavior of this code. Can someone explain it to me?

Tags: c++

I am working with C++ and trying to wrap my brain around pointers. I have done the simple...

```
int a = 5;
int* b = &a;
int c = *b;
```

and then `cout` all the results. But I have then gone on to change the variable `a` to a different number and see the results, but only `a` changes and not the variable `c`. That is what I am not understanding. Can someone please explain to me why?

Comment: Put your complete code.

Comment: @InQusitive No need. In fact, that would just be noise.

Comment: Please improve the title so that it describes the question.

Answer (score 3):

`int c = *b;` creates `c` and sets its initial value to the value pointed to by `b`. It does not create an enduring relationship between `c` and `b`. When `*b` or `a` are later changed, it does not change the value stored in `c`.

Answer (score 2):

`c` is not a pointer. It is an integer.

When you initialised it, you gave it the value `*b`, which *at that time* was 5.

But from then on it's its own thing and has no relationship to `b` or to `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the wonderful world of pointers (my condolences). Although confusing at first, a few rules apply to pointers that make them very flexible. Pointers are just that: pointers to a location in memory.

The first line of code does not (directly) involve pointers. You the told computer to make a box named `a` - this box will contain an integer number - and then store the value `5` inside the box. In the background, the computer has to remember the *location* of the box you just made. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to use the box or the value!

The next instruction is more interesting. You make another box called `b`. Instead of putting a value in box, you told computer to put a *sign* in it. The computer knows you want it to make a sign because of the asterisk between the keyword `int` and the letter `b` - in C++, the asterisk marks a pointer when used in a declaration statement (typically on the left hand side of the single-equals sign, or sometimes simply before the semicolon when there is no single-equals sign). Then, you told the computer to write the *location* of the box `a` (indicated by an ampersand, the address operator) on the sign and put the sign inside box `b`.

**Note**: `b` contains a very specific kind of sign that is not interchangeable with a sign that points to, say, a char.

And now the hard part, the final line of code. Here you told computer to make a second integer-number box, called `c`. Then you told computer to take a picture of the value inside the box sitting at the location on the sign that `b` contains. This is my metaphor for the dereference operation (indicated by an asterisk in a statement that will be evaluated, typically on the right-hand side of the single-equals sign, or perhaps in a loop conditional, etc.). The computer looks at the location and sees that the value sitting there right now is `5`. So the last line of code is evaluated and reduced to `int c = 5`.

The box `c` is now separate from and independent of `a`. So when you change either, the other is not affected. `b` was simply used as a roundabout proxy for `a`. You could have accomplished the same result with `int c = a`.

But believe me, for more advanced and dynamic applications, the ability to refer to a memory location instead of a value is *game-changing*. In fact, pointers are at the root of why today we can use easier to grasp, higher-level languages like Python and Java.

Best of luck in life and learning.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @user4581301. I see where you're coming from.